# SetProgress on a ProgressBar spinner

Tags: android, progress-bar

I'm trying to develop an app which shows a progressbar spinner.
Google documentation about progressbar is not clear and i haven't found interesting posts on the web.

I want the spinner progress to change (accordingly to setProgress) as it happens in a normal horizontal progress bar.
At first i tried with this to see if it is possible to do so:

```
 <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="33"/>
```

The progressbar shows up but it is spinning like it is on underterminate mode. Why?

Comment: method already available for setting progress... progressBar.setProgress(progress);

Comment: @Richa just tried that one, with setMax(100) as well. As i expected, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

if the setProgress is called too manytimes the Progress is Showing 100% Directly,
Try to use handler by setting a delay of 100ms

```
Message msg = Handler.obtainMessage();
msg.arg1 = HandlerMessages.UPDATE_PROGRESS.ordinal();
msg.obj = progress;
Handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 100);
```